# Black screen when boot

Tags: horus

everytime i try to boot in, lockscreen appears, then i put the password and it just displays a black screen, sometimes with sound (when i press volume + or -). So far the only way i can succesfully use Elementary OS is adding "nomodeset" in the grub everytime i'm login in, it's the only way it works normally, in fact thats the way i managed to configure the system, but it gets annoying really fast, so i'm looking for a fix

I'm using EOS 7, in a HP x2 210 g2 tablet/laptop
2gb of ram
32gb emmc
Intel atom x5-z8350

Comment: That 2GB of RAM is a big problem. There just isn't enough for the GUI to work with. The [system requirements](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) state that 4GB is the minimum. If you *really* want to run Linux on that machine, you may need to run a very light desktop, such as Xfce or MATE 